# 3.13.0-24 Kernel and NVIDIA Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed Nvidia drivers from additional software. Everything was working fine. After a few days an update notifier came out to install kernel 3.13.0-24 (and bunch of other stuff) and suddenly when I try to login it gives me an error that it had to start in low graphics mode. Before that I saw a line that said "NVidia is tainting kernel" or something like that.

I went into recovery mode and purged all nvidia content (purge nvidia*) but now the resolution is 640*480 and I can't change it, also poor graphical performance.

It seems that the new kernel is somehow incompatible with any NVidia driver. I tried all other versions (337, 318, 310) but to no avail.

Anyone have any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `3.13.0-24-generic` 64-bit version with the 337.12 Nvidia driver. Today I changed to the 334.21 Nvidia version. All is good. This means that we know the 337/334 versions of Nvidia do work with the `3.13.0-24-generic` kernel version.

What I suggest is to first troubleshoot some of the problems mentioned in [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433)

Specially the part about looking for any left over nvidia configuration files (Maybe `/etc/modprobe.conf`). If the purging worked correctly you should have loaded Ubuntu using the Nvidia nouveau driver which supports resolutions higher than 640. Of course, I am assuming you don't have an Nvidia 8xx or one of the latest 700 series which still have some minor issues with Nouveau.

Check to see if no Nvidia config files were left behind and use only the Xorg PPA because the Nvidia package from the Nvidia site has other ways of installing (and leaving) packages.